# Gaps between exectuting code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say i have 20 lines of code:

```
alert('x1');
alert('x2');
alert('x3');
.....
```

How can i execute the lines or say the functions one after another with a gap of a half second?

Normaly it would look something like this, but for me this solution is too long:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert('x1');
},500);
setTimeout(function(){
    alert('x2');
},1000);
setTimeout(function(){
    alert('x3');
},500);
```

I thought in putting all of my functions in a array and then let them execute with gaps! The problem with this is that i would have to give all of my functions names and i try to avoid this! How would you handle my problem?

Comment: The problem you've got here is that the `alert` is modal, so will prevent the UI updating while it is visible. Therefore all three alerts will appear immediately after each other if you don't cancel them quick enough. Is that just a poor choice of example code, or do you actually need to work with `alert`?

Comment: Why would you need this kind of behaviour? And your sample code is wrong, timeouts should be nested

Comment: In JavaScript, functions don't need to have a name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var funcs = [];
funcs.push(function (){alert("x1");});
funcs.push(function (){alert("x2");});
funcs.push(function (){alert("x3");});
funcs.push(function (){alert("x4");});
funcs.push(function (){alert("x5");});
funcs.push(function (){alert("x6");});
//...

var counter =0;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
  funcs[counter]();
  counter++
  if (counter==funcs.length){
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
},500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;   
var t = function run(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        count++;
        if(count == 1){
        alert('x1');
        }
        //and so on
    run(); 
    },500);      
} 
clearTimeout(t);
```

Comment: setTimeout will only get fired once

Comment: @ChrisC oh yeah, sorry, needs some recursion

Comment: I think you mean function not Function and you appear to have a stack overflow now (which is appropriate for this site)